# getting access to dom elements from inserted html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, insert

I want to get access to DOM-Elements which are added with jquery from an external HTML-File.

Here's my first part of the code where I add the HTML:

```
$.get("resources/game/game_menu.html").success(function(data) {
    $("#gameView2").html(data);
});
```

the "game_menu.html" looks just like this (atm for testing)

```
<div id="gameMenu" class="gameMenu">
    <button id="startGame" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to get access to the elements with jquery which looks like this:

```
$("#startGame").click(startGame());
$("#gameMenu").someFunction(someContext);
```

But both just don't work. How is possible to get access to ALL of the DOM-Elements.
Can anyone help me?

Thx,
myr0

Comment: Where do you put the last two commands? Can you show the whole code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$(document).on("click", "#startgame", startGame());` for dynamically generated content.

See [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) for the reason why you have to do this.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "#startgame", startGame);`

Comment: `$(document).on("click","#startGame", function(){
        startGame()
        });` this fixed it! thx!

Comment: Alex is right, you can just pass in startGame instead of function() { startGame() }, but the way you've done it should be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Define the event inside

```
$.get("resources/game/game_menu.html").success(function(data) {
    $("#gameView2").html(data);
    $("#startGame").click(startGame());
});
```

Those elements not exist in DOM.

Comment: `startGame` shouldn't have `()` I think, as it's a callback.